# Using bison rule inside another rule

Tags: parsing, bison, lalr

Let's assume I have grammar like this:

```
expr : expr '-' expr { $$ = $1 - $3; }
     | "Function" '(' expr ',' expr ')' { $$ = ($3 - $5) * 2; }
     | NUMBER { $$ = $1; };
```

How can use rule

```
expr : expr '-' expr { $$ = $1 - $3; }
```

inside

```
expr : "Function" '(' expr ',' expr ')' { $$ = ($3 - $5) * 2; }
```

Because implementation of `$1 - $3` is repeated? It would be much better if I can use already implemented subtraction from rule one and only add multiplication with 2. This is just the basic example, but I have very big grammar with lot of repeating calculations.

Comment: Its not clear what calculation you want "Function" to perform.....also in that rule there is no value for $1. It is $3 and $5 that have values....

Comment: @Brian Tompsett you are correct. Because of simple example Function is fictional and it should only represent that I want to perform SOME calculation that is using partially the same calculation as in above rule. And yes, it was supposed to be ($3 - $5) * 2

Comment: Now your question makes even less sense. I don't think anyone understands what you are trying to achieve. You have done the calculation.....

Comment: @Brian Tompsett what I want is:
expr : "Function" '(' expr ',' expr ')' 
{
    /* instead of $3 - $5 */
    /* can I explain the parser to go through expr ; expr '-' expr return the result and continue here? */ 
    $$ = RESULT * 2; 
}

Comment: No. Still completely unclear. You are obviously assuming something your are not explaining fully. Edit the question to put more explanation of the problem you are trying t solve. You have reduced your example to something that makes no sense; as you did with the last question also.

Comment: I think the answer is to define some helper functions, so that you end up with `expr : expr '-' expr { $$ = confabulate($1, $3); }` and `expr : "Function" '(' expr ',' expr ')' { $$ = confabulate($3, $5) * 2; }`. If that's not the answer, I don't understand the question either.

Comment: Well I tried to simplify things. Rule 
`expr : expr '-' expr` is working with complex data structures so subtraction is pain in the neck, implemented with 100+ lines of code.
Now, another rule is
`expr : "Function" '(' expr ',' expr ')'` uses the same implementation as for subtraction but it adds some 20+ lines more. What I wanted is not to implement the already big code from subtraction again. I simply wanted to explain the parser to use rule `expr : expr '-' expr` and then to continue, only to avoid duplicating the large piece of code

Comment: You just use functions in C. This is not a bison problem. Only a C programming problem. The solution proposed by @rici is what you need.

Comment: Well, I disagree. I know that I can solve this using functions, but my point was to learn bison feature if such feature exists.